# Invalid left-hand side in assignment javascript1.7

Tags: javascript

JavaScript1.7 error in **GoogleChrome**

**Example:**

```
var x, y;
try {
 [x, y] = ["1", "2"];
 document.write(x+": "+y);
} catch(e){
 console.log(e);
}
```

**catch erro:**
Invalid left-hand side in assignment JavaScript1.7

I need actually is to test if the browser supports **javascript1.7**

What I need is to actually test if the browser supports javascript1.7
But without using this kind of code:

jsversion = 1.7;

This code beyond invalid by the w3c, is also working with global variables,
which can be a very bad thing (can cause conflicts and other problems)

I tried using the following code (but error occurs in **"strict"**)

```
var i=0;
try{
    yield i;
} catch(ee) {
    document.write(ee);
}
```

So this is what I need to do, to test if the browser supports javascript1.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var isESNext;
try {
  eval('(function () { var x, y; [x, y] = [1, 2]; })()');
  isESNext = true;
} catch (ex) {
  isESNext = false;
}
```

This uses `eval` to parse a bit of code which uses [ES.next](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts)  pattern decomposition but which is not valid EcmaScript 5.  The rest of the code which declares and assigns `isESNext` is valid EcmaScript 3 code though so should run on all browsers.

The problem you're running into is due to [Chapter 16](http://es5.github.com/#x16):

> ## 16 Errors
>
> An early error is an error that can be detected and reported prior to the evaluation of any construct in the Program containing the error. An implementation must report early errors in a Program prior to the first evaluation of that Program.
>
> ...
>
> An implementation must treat any instance of the following kinds of errors as an early error:
>
> - Any syntax error.

But the code snippet above gets around the early error because

> Early errors in `eval` code are reported at the time `eval` is called

Comment: Did not you read?? This flaw in **Chrome**, my doubt is another ... I'm sorry to have been thick, but I explained the problem.

I'll start, I need something that works in all browsers indicating that the browser supports **javascript1.7** if possible. Thanks;

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Please be civil.

Comment: I apologized already, ok? I wish you could, you read everything I wrote in my question to understand my doubts, and if you can help me I would be grateful.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, I see "JavaScript 1.7" in your code, but I'm unclear where you say you tried using `eval` around the 1.7 specific constructs and it didn't work.

Comment: @ Mike_Samuel
So I consider that googlechrome not support "javascript1.7", as if considering it only supports up to "javascript1.6"?? Thanks

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, Google-chrome support EcmaScript 3.1 and parts of EcmaScript 5.  JavaScript 1.7 is a Mozilla creation.  No other browsers support JavaScript > 1.5, and instead support varying versions of EcmaScript.  See [Relationship between JavaScript and EcmaScript version numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/JavaScript_Overview#Relationship_between_JavaScript_Versions_and_ECMAScript_Editions)